# Should Twitter Bootstrap Row/Col be used for layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for the beginnings of a very basic web store. I began using it mostly for some easy styling and whatnot, but as I got I find myself using more of their layout features.

One thing I'm curious about: I recall being told that I should, in general, not use HTML tables for page layout. I.e. it's fine to use them for tabulated data (its intended purpose) but not for arranging elements on a page.

My question is this: should the Bootstrap row and col classes be used for page layout, or exclusively for tabulated data? It seems very similar to using tables, but it also seems like they built Bootstrap with row/col being used for responsive layouts. Why are they different, if they are?

Comment: of course yes! They are meant for layout only!

Comment: Faust's points are valid. However, to play devil's advocate, I'd point out that names like "row" and "col" indicate presentation of a specific sort and thus are not ideal names. I tend to favor names which reflect the content and have nothing to do with the presentation. This can be quite difficult (and isn't always the correct solution) but it does make you think about your markup and styles!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstraps row and column classes are fine.They are not the same as using tables (`table`, `tr`, and `td` tags) for non-tabular-data layouts.

The problem with tables for layouts is two-fold

1. Their *rigidity*: you can't convert `<td>`s in a row into a structure that operates like floats (at least not just with CSS), so your only recourse to changing the layout will be going in and re-arranging the markup structure, like ripping the  cells out of a table and converting them to divs. This makes them quite useless for *responsive design* (there's your key buzz-word)
2. Their *semantics*: tables are supposed to say "hey, I'm an array of ordered data" so for humans reading HTML code, your muddying the waters by using them for page-layout. It's also (theoretically) an issue for search-engine optimization.

Neither of these points apply to bootstrap `row` and `col-` classes, or for using `display:table` (etc.) in general

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Bootstrap's CSS helper classes, "row" and "col". They access the Bootstrap Grid. Don't confuse this with using HTML tags "table", "td", "tr", etc. for displaying content, which yes should only be used for tabular data.

Comment: Why are they better/acceptable? I'd like to be able to defend this approach to someone who only know "Tables BAD" if it comes to that.

Comment: The table tag was ALWAYS intended to be used for displaying tables of data, hence the name. Before CSS capabilities really grew and caught on, people 'hacked' tables to display images & whatnot without borders and cellspacing in order to create a facsimile of visually structured design. This has NOTHING to do with CSS rules that simply *happen* to be named ".row" and ".col". They could've just as easily been called ".elephant" and ".rhino". The name is semantically useful but otherwise arbitrary. [Read up on simple topics, please](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design)

Answer (score 0):

You've got the most of it!

You should use bootstrap classes (row,col-) and not table structure coz of the foll reasons:

1) The classes allow you to have a responsive layout [if you see the code, you'll find everything defined in %, so it helps you get a fluid layout]

2) Also if you want the body content to have a centered layout [say 10% gutter space of both -left and right side], doing this with table is quite a tedious process. While if you use bootstrap, you can do this using offset classes

3) They can be easily switched from fluid to static and vice-versa layouts.